# In an Espresso Test, how do I get a resource using ActivityTestScenario

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I'm following the [Android Code Lab for Espresso testing](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-espresso-for-ui-testing?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#4)

It is outdated because it uses `ActivityTestRule` instead of the recommended [ActivityScenarioRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/ext/junit/rules/ActivityScenarioRule)

**Outdated Code Snippets**

The rule

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class SpinnerSelectionTest {
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
                 MainActivity.class);
```

The test

```
@Test
public void iterateSpinnerItems() {
String[] myArray = 
     mActivityRule.getActivity().getResources()
     .getStringArray(R.array.labels_array);
}
```

**Recommended Code**

I have figured out the Rule

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class SpinnerSelectionTest {

@Rule
public ActivityScenarioRule<EspressoSpinnerActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityScenarioRule(
        EspressoSpinnerActivity.class);
```

The test

**How to get the resource `R.array.labels_array` as it was done in the old code (above)?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. The key is to get the context using `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()`

Create a helper function to retrieve the string array resource values

```
private String[] getResourceArray(int id) {
    Context targetContext = 
        InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();

    return targetContext.getResources().getStringArray(id);
}
```

Then in the @Test method, you can retrieve the array

```
 @Test
 public void iterateSpinnerItems() {
    String[] arr = getResourceArray(R.array.labels_array);

}
```